# Dynamics of a System via Orthogonal Diagonalization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, density-operator, linear-algebra, time-evolution

About a week ago, I was working with the time evolution of a density operator for a given initial state $\rho_0$ given a specific Hamiltonian $\mathbf{H}$.
My fist approach was to find an operator $\mathbf{U}$ such that:
$$\rho_t = \mathbf{U}\rho_0\mathbf{U}^\dagger$$
Where:
$$\mathbf{U} = e^{-i\frac{t}{\hbar}\mathbf{H}}$$
Since then, I have been told about other ways to tackle the problem. The one I am trying to understand now is the approach one could take by an Orthogonal Diagonalization. For reference, this method should follow the algorithm described in the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_diagonalization

Although I feel familiar to this approach, having covered it in some basic linear algebra course, I do not yet see how it could be used to study the time evolution of a system $\rho_0$ only by being given a Hamiltonian $\mathbf{H}$.

Edit:
This is how I tried to approach this

\begin{align}
    \mathbf{H}_{AB} &= \mathbf{\sigma}_{xA} \otimes \mathbb{I}_B + \mathbb{I}_{A} \otimes \mathbf{\sigma}_{xB} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \mathbf{I}\\
    \mathbf{I} & 0
    \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_x & 0\\
    0 & \sigma_x
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_x & \mathbf{I}\\
    \mathbf{I}& \sigma_x
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    \mathbf{\sigma}_x &= |0\rangle \langle1|+ |1\rangle \langle0|\\
\end{align}
$\cdot \mathbf{\rho}_A(0) = p_0\left|0\rangle \langle0\right| + p_1\left|1\rangle \langle1\right| =\mathbf{\rho}_B(0) $\
$\cdot p_0+p_1 = 1 $ and $ p_i \geq 0$.\
$\cdot \rho_{AB}(0) = \mathbf{\rho}_A(0)\otimes\mathbf{\rho}_B(0) = \begin{bmatrix}
p_0 \rho_B &0\\
0& p_1\rho_B
\end{bmatrix}$

Through the use of the definition of eigen-vectors $\mathbf{A}\overline{x}=\lambda\overline{x}$, we can arrive to construct a projection operator $\mathbf{P}$ (s.t. $\mathbf{P}\mathbf{P}^\dagger=\mathbf{I}$).\
We can use said operator to apply a change of basis to $\mathbf{H}_{AB}$ and rewrite it in the following form through $\mathbf{spectral-decomposition}$:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{H}_{AB} = \sum_i \lambda_i |\lambda_i\rangle\langle\lambda_i|
\end{align}
This will enable us to be able to construct  a linear unitary operator $\mathbf{U}$ through:
\begin{align}
   f(\mathbf{H}) = \sum_i f(\lambda_i)|\lambda_i\rangle\langle\lambda_i|\\
    \mathbf{U} = e^{-itH} = \sum_i e^{-it\lambda_i}|\lambda_i\rangle\langle\lambda_i|
\end{align}

From here I start the process of Diagonalization of the Hamiltonian

From the $\mathbf{spectral-theorem}$ we know that: since $\mathbf{H}_{AB}$ is a $\mathbf{NxN}$ self adjoint operator, its eigenvalues will form a N-dimensional orthogonal set.

We can start by solving the characteristic equation of $\mathbf{H}_{AB}$:
\begin{align}
    \det\begin{vmatrix}
\sigma_x-\lambda\mathbf{I} &\mathbf{I} \\ 
 \mathbf{I}&\sigma_x -\lambda\mathbf{I}
\end{vmatrix} =     
\det\begin{vmatrix}
 -\lambda& 1  &1  &0 \\ 
 1&-\lambda   & 0 &1 \\
 1& 0  & -\lambda &1 \\
 0&   1&  1&-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow ...\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1 = 2\\ 
\lambda_2 = -2\\
\lambda_3 = 0\\
\lambda_4 = 0\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align}
From this, it is possible to derive all the eigen-vectors belonging to each eigen-value.\
\
For $\lambda = 0$:
\begin{align}
    (\mathbf{H}_{AB}-0\mathbf{I})\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0& 1  &1  &0 \\ 
 1&0   & 0 &1 \\
 1& 0  & 0 &1 \\
 0&   1&  1&0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{0}
\end{align}
Looking at eq(5), we can notice how the matrix-vector multiplication would yield a set of two distinct equations:
\begin{align}
    -x_1&=x_4\\
    -x_2&=x_3\\
\nonumber    \textup{meaning:}\\
\overrightarrow{u}_1 &= u_1\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}\\
\overrightarrow{u}_2 &= u_2\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align}
\
For $\lambda = 2$:
\begin{align}
       (\mathbf{H}_{AB}-2\mathbf{I})\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -2& 1  &1  &0 \\ 
 1&-2   & 0 &1 \\
 1& 0  & -2 &1 \\
 0&   1&  1&-2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{0}
\end{align}
Now we notice that the matrix-vector multiplication would yield a system of equations with solution:
\begin{align}
    x_1&=x_2=x_3=x_4\\
\nonumber    \textup{meaning:}\\
    \overrightarrow{u}_3 &= u_3\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
\
For $\lambda = -2$
\begin{align}
       (\mathbf{H}_{AB}+2\mathbf{I})\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
 2& 1  &1  &0 \\ 
 1&2   & 0 &1 \\
 1& 0  & 2 &1 \\
 0&   1&  1&2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{0}
\end{align}
Now we notice that the matrix-vector multiplication would yield a system of equations with solution:
\begin{align}
    -x_1&=x_2=x_3=-x_4\\
\nonumber    \textup{meaning:}\\
    \overrightarrow{u}_4 &= u_4\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\
-1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

After the normalization of vectors $\overrightarrow{u}_i$, we can finally construct $\mathbf{P}$ as such:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{P} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 0& 1 &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
 0 &-1& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
 -1 & 0& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Using the projection operator $\mathbf{P}$ we can finally diagonalize $\mathbf{H}_{AB}$:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{P}^\dagger\mathbf{H}_{AB}\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&2&0\\
    0&0&0&-2
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Henceforth the unitary operator will be:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{U} = e^{-it0}\begin{bmatrix}
    1&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0
    \end{bmatrix} + 
    e^{-it0}\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0
    \end{bmatrix} +&
    e^{-i2t}\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&1&0\\
    0&0&0&0
    \end{bmatrix} +
    e^{2it0}\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&0\\
    0&0&0&1
    \end{bmatrix}=\\
    \mathbf{U}&=\begin{bmatrix}
    1&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&e^{-i2t}&0\\
    0&0&0&e^{i2t}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Finding the energy change and final state of the system:

Now, all that is left to do, is to find the time evolution of our composite system:
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{U}\rho_{AB}(0)\mathbf{U}^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix}
    1&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&e^{-i2t}&0\\
    0&0&0&e^{i2t}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    (p_0)²&0&0&0\\
    0&(p_1)²&0&0\\
    0&0&(p_0)²&0\\
    0&0&0&(p_1)²
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&e^{i2t}&0\\
    0&0&0&e^{-i2t}
    \end{bmatrix}=\\
    \\=    \begin{bmatrix}
    (p_0)²&0&0&0\\
    0&(p_1)²&0&0\\
    0&0&(p_0)²&0\\
    0&0&0&(p_1)²
    \end{bmatrix} = \rho_{AB}(t)=\rho_{AB}(0)
\end{align}
Henceforth this leaves us with no Energy change to calculate because $\rho_{AB}(0) =\rho_{AB}(t)$, and therefore the energy change will be zero.

Comment: Since you asked in a comment section of your previous question: I think I don't understand what you want to do at all. Maybe you can elaborate a bit more? Do you want to diagonalize the Hamiltonian? Then you could use something like this (?): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Computing_the_matrix_exponential

Comment: Are you familiar with the equivalent problem in terms of pure states $|\psi\rangle$?

Comment: hey, took me a couple of day to come back, but I edited my answer with a full procedure of how I tried to approach this.
It is a long-ish text so you may not want to even try, but I have a question regarding this:
I was told that f(H)=∑if(λi)|λi⟩⟨λi| holds true in this case, but do you have a soruce I could go and look up the proof for this?

Comment: I just took a glance at your edit (note that there are some latex errors). All in all, you diagonalized the Hamiltonian and then used this to obtain $U$, correct? But what is your question? As I said, I haven't checked the calculations, but of course you are allowed to work in a basis which simplifies your calculations. Regarding the question in the comment: Have a look at [this physics SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408722/functions-of-operators) or [this math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782789/using-calculus-results-for-functions-of-operators).

Comment: there was no question really, I think the edit solves the problem.
Although you did manage to give me resources to help me derive the f(H) formula, thank you.